# How to properly handle page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a form on my page with many fields. I save field values in the datastore once user input a value (without waiting for form submission). Some score is calculated based on field values and displayed to the user. I also generate user's client id and store that in user's cookies for one hour.

I am not sure what should happen when user refreshed the page in browser:

1. if user pressed F5 in FF, then field values are still displayed in the browser;
2. when user pressed Ctrl+F5, then values are cleared.

In both cases I don't want to create new record for this user, so client id should remain the same. But in scenario (1) I should NOT clear field values in datastore and its score, but I should do it in scenario (2). How can I recognize that on the server side?

Comment: Why are you creating the client id client side?

Comment: @ShayErlichmen, it is created on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

The two scenarios you have explained are behaviours built into your browser. Most browsers will try to resubmit form data if you press F5 on a page where data has been submitted. This is to try to avoid data being lost by the average user.

It is as though you were to enter the site, complete the form and click Submit all over again.

To avoid handling this data again you could generate a random key and store it in a hidden form field. Then when the data is submitted, save this key in a session variable. If the data is resubmitted, you can put a check around your postback which compares the random key in the form data to that in the session. If they are the same then the data has already been handled.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SESSION ID when the user enters the Registration page and store it in the database. I think session id will change only when user close the browser.

If user refresh the page retrive the values from the database with the SESSION ID.

When user click submit button and successfully query the values to database. Destroy the SESSION ID reset the form fields...

Answer (score 0):

The best way, when you load the page, you should check it if there was any content for each form field already saved in db otherwise try some client side form field cache technique.

Comment: What should I do if it is saved in the datastore? Display that in according field? (actually I have ~150 fields)